# Prolog How to write a predicate sum 3 max values in list?

Tags: prolog

How to write a predicate sum 3 max values in list?
max3(L,X)

Example:

```
max3([1,7,9,3,5],X).
X = 21.
```

Comment: Probably fastest to use https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=msort/2 , then sum the last 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point:

```
% Can potentially change order of the list in Rest
list_max_rest([H|T], Max, Rest) :-
    list_max_rest_(T, H, Max, Rest).
    
list_max_rest_([], Max, Max, []).
list_max_rest_([H|T], P, Max, [P|Rest]) :-
    H @> P,
    !,
    list_max_rest_(T, H, Max, Rest).
list_max_rest_([H|T], P, Max, [H|Rest]) :-
    list_max_rest_(T, P, Max, Rest).
```

Usage:

```
?- list_max_rest([2,1,200,9], Max, Res).
Max = 200,
Res = [1, 2, 9].
```

Use that 3 times...

Answer (score 0):

```
max3(Ls, X) :-
    select(A, Ls,  Ls2),
    select(B, Ls2, Ls3),
    select(C, Ls3, Ls4),
    A >= B,
    B >= C,
    \+ (member(Q, Ls4), Q > C),
    X is A+B+C.
```

Take `A` from the list, `B` from the remainder, `C` from that remainder, they must be A>=B>=C, and there must not be a member `Q` left in the remainder which is bigger than C. Add those up.

This is not efficient; brebs' suggestion of:

```
max3(Ls, X) :-
    sort(0, @>=, Ls, [A,B,C|_]),
    X is A+B+C.
```

is neater